# Fitting data to multimodal distributions with scipy, matplotlib

Tags: distributions, python, fitting, curve-fitting

I have a dataset that I would like to fit to a known probability distribution. The intention is to use the fitted PDF in a data generator - such that I can sample data from the known (fitted) PDF. Data will be used for simulation purposes. At the moment I am just sampling from a normal distribution, which is inconsistent with the real-data, therefore simulation results are not accurate.

I first wanted to use the following method : Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python)?

My first thought was to fit it to a weibull distribution, but the data is actually multimodal (picture attached). So I guess I need to combine multiple distributions and then fit the data to the resulting dist, is that right ? Maybe combine a gaussian AND a weibull distirbution ?

How can I use the scipy fit() function with a mixed/multimodal distribution ?

Also I would want to do this in Python (i.e. scipy/numpy/matplotlib), as the data generator is written in Python.

Tips on doing this in other languages/tools such as R/matlab is also helpful. I've also left this question on Stackoverflow, but then I guess this site is more suited to this question.

[image]